# MSI: Invalid SQL-Syntax

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installer

does anyone use "Exe to msi Converter free" from http://www.qwertylab.com/FreeTools.aspx? I evaluate this tool at the moment. Basically it creates a MSI Wrapper for EXE-Setups passing the Parameter for a Silent Installation to the included standard EXE Installer.

When I run the MSI manually everything works fine. But when I want to deploy them via GPO the following error is logged:

Source: Software Installation
Event-ID: 107
Error: Invalid SQL-Syntax (original Errormessage is in german: Die SQL-Abfragesyntax ist ungültig oder wird nicht unterstützt.)

The Result is that the software isn't deployed.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!